# Scala scope saying that object.propery doesn't exist but left panel in eclipse shows it

Tags: eclipse, scala, scope

I am trying to build a simple program however it looks as if I went into a small problem which I simply do not understand:

I have the following code:

```
    package objsets

import common._
import TweetReader._

/**
 * A class to represent tweets.
 */
class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) {
  override def toString: String =
    "User: " + user + "\n" +
    "Text: " + text + " [" + retweets + "]"
}

/**
 * This represents a set of objects of type `Tweet` in the form of a binary search
 * tree. Every branch in the tree has two children (two `TweetSet`s). There is an
 * invariant which always holds: for every branch `b`, all elements in the left
 * subtree are smaller than the tweet at `b`. The eleemnts in the right subtree are
 * larger.
 *
 * Note that the above structure requires us to be able to compare two tweets (we
 * need to be able to say which of two tweets is larger, or if they are equal). In
 * this implementation, the equality / order of tweets is based on the tweet's text
 * (see `def incl`). Hence, a `TweetSet` could not contain two tweets with the same
 * text from different users.
 *
 *
 * The advantage of representing sets as binary search trees is that the elements
 * of the set can be found quickly. If you want to learn more you can take a look
 * at the Wikipedia page [1], but this is not necessary in order to solve this
 * assignment.
 * 
 * [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
 */
abstract class TweetSet {

  def isEmpty: Boolean
  /**
   * This method takes a predicate and returns a subset of all the elements
   * in the original set for which the predicate is true.
   *
   * Question: Can we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
  def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet

  /**
   * This is a helper method for `filter` that propagetes the accumulated tweets.
   */
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` that is the union of `TweetSet`s `this` and `that`.
   *
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
   def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet;

  /**
   * Returns the tweet from this set which has the greatest retweet count.
   *
   * Calling `mostRetweeted` on an empty set should throw an exception of
   * type `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.
   *
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
  def mostRetweeted: Tweet = ???

  /**
   * Returns a list containing all tweets of this set, sorted by retweet count
   * in descending order. In other words, the head of the resulting list should
   * have the highest retweet count.
   *
   * Hint: the method `remove` on TweetSet will be very useful.
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
  def descendingByRetweet: TweetList


  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` which contains all elements of this set, and the
   * the new element `tweet` in case it does not already exist in this set.
   *
   * If `this.contains(tweet)`, the current set is returned.
   */
  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` which excludes `tweet`.
   */
  def remove(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Tests if `tweet` exists in this `TweetSet`.
   */
  def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean

  /**
   * This method takes a function and applies it to every element in the set.
   */
  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit
}

class Empty extends TweetSet {

  def descendingByRetweet() = Nil
  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = that  
  def isEmpty = true

  def filter(p: Tweet=> Boolean): TweetSet = new Empty()

  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = new Empty()


  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean = false

  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = new NonEmpty(tweet, new Empty, new Empty)

  def remove(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = this

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = ()
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {

  def descendingByRetweet = {


    def iterateAndAddList(list: TweetList,first: Boolean): TweetList = {

      val current: Tweet = greatestCurrent()
      if(current != Nil && first != true){
      list.head = current
      list.isEmpty = false
      list.tail = Nil
      remove(current)
      iterateAndAddList(list,false)
      }else list

    }

    def greatestCurrent():Tweet = {
      new Tweet("a","b",21)
    }

    iterateAndAddList(Nil,true)

  }

  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = (left.union(right)).union(that).incl(elem)
  val isEmpty = false

  def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = filterAcc(p,new Empty)

  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {

    if(left.isEmpty && right.isEmpty) acc
    else if(p(elem)){ left.filterAcc(p,acc.incl(elem)).union(right.filterAcc(p,acc.incl(elem)))}
    else left.filterAcc(p,acc).union(right.filterAcc(p,acc))


  }


  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  def contains(x: Tweet): Boolean =
    if (x.text < elem.text) left.contains(x)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) right.contains(x)
    else true

  def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
    if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this
  }

  def remove(tw: Tweet): TweetSet =
    if (tw.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.remove(tw), right)
    else if (elem.text < tw.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.remove(tw))
    else left.union(right)

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = {
    f(elem)
    left.foreach(f)
    right.foreach(f)
  }
}









//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
















trait TweetList {
  def head: Tweet
  def tail: TweetList
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit =
    if (!isEmpty) {
      f(head)
      tail.foreach(f)
    }
}

object Nil extends TweetList {
  def head = throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("head of EmptyList")
  def tail = throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("tail of EmptyList")
  def isEmpty = true
}

class Cons(val head: Tweet, val tail: TweetList) extends TweetList {
  def isEmpty = false
}


object GoogleVsApple {
  val google = List("android", "Android", "galaxy", "Galaxy", "nexus", "Nexus")
  val apple = List("ios", "iOS", "iphone", "iPhone", "ipad", "iPad")

  lazy val googleTweets: TweetSet = ???
  lazy val appleTweets: TweetSet = ???

  /**
   * A list of all tweets mentioning a keyword from either apple or google,
   * sorted by the number of retweets.
   */
  lazy val trending: TweetList = ???
}

object Main extends App {
  // Print the trending tweets
  GoogleVsApple.trending foreach println
}
```

(It is from the scala coursera course. This question does not relate to the course in any matter. I am not asking for a solution).

My problem is that in the descendingByOrder function in the helper function ( in the NonEmpty class) the

```
list.head
list.isEmpty
list.tail
```

For some reason appear to be hidden? Shouldn't this properties be accessible ?

Comment: I don't see any `descendingByOrder` do you mean `descendingByRetweet `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what do you mean by `appearing hidden` but one of the problems could be that here

```
def descendingByRetweet = {

  def iterateAndAddList(list: TweetList,first: Boolean): TweetList = {
    val current: Tweet = greatestCurrent()
    if(current != Nil && first != true){
      list.head = current
      list.isEmpty = false
      list.tail = Nil
      remove(current)
      iterateAndAddList(list,false)
    }
    else list
  }

  def greatestCurrent():Tweet = {
    new Tweet("a","b",21)
  }

  iterateAndAddList(Nil,true)

}
```

You are reassigning to `def`, `TweetList` are immutable and you cannot assign properties to them, instead you could create a new element that then can be passed to the function and keep recursing:

```
def descendingByRetweet = {

  def iterateAndAddList(list: TweetList,first: Boolean): TweetList = {
    val current: Tweet = greatestCurrent()
    if(current != Nil && first != true) iterateAndAddList(new Cons(current, Nil), false)
    else list
  }

  def greatestCurrent():Tweet = {
    new Tweet("a","b",21)
  }

  iterateAndAddList(Nil,true)

}
```

This is the way to recurse on immutable collections in Scala, you always need to create a new object.

Comment: It's a trait. But I'm adressing to Cons and Nil which implement TweetList and hence trying to achieve polymorphism. Anyhow even if they are empty why would the compiler return an error?

Comment: No method is invoked. Non at all. The compiler fails running and throws an exception saying that TweetList.head is not possible. But it should be as it has those elements as parameters? And any class that extends it should. What am I missing?

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't compile, `list.head` is possible but you are reassigning to val in `list.head = current`.

Comment: How can I then modify the head and tail of a Cons and Nil ( which are both a TweetList) and both inherit the head and tail properties?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, I didn't understand what `remove(current)`was supposed to do since it returns a `TweetList` and you were not assigni its result to any variable so I thought that should be the tail of the `Cons`, anyway you can pass a `Nil` instead of the result of `remove(current)` to the `Cons` object if it suits your need.

Comment: it returns a tweetSet not a tweetList. I'm deleting a item from the tweetSet because if I don't the biggest item will always be the same. Also you are creating a new TweetList every time which means that the results are not stored?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54333/discussion-between-bula-and-ende-neu).